# Regex Replace Whilst Retaining MetaInfo?

Tags: regex

Although im using c# and the .net lib, im interested in a regex-only solution for some text replacement, and am a bit confused by the final hurdle. (Im using http://gskinner.com/RegExr)

Ive got the string

```
"Foo {0} Bar {1}"
```

I can use `{[0-9]}` to match, but when it comes to replacing, id like to keep the number, i.e. would produce:

```
"Foo $0$ Bar $1$"
```

If I had decided I wanted to replace curly braces with dollar symbols (for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `\{(\d+)\}` with `$\1$`

The parenthesis in the regex "captures" the enclosed portion and it can be accessed in the replacement string using `\1` syntax. So if you have multiple capturing groups, the first one is `\1` and second one is `\2` etc.

Some regex flavors follow `$1` instead of `\1` - in that case you should escape explicit `$` symbol as `$$` in the replacement string. Also, the `\` character itself needs to be escaped as usual in the strings.

The curly braces are special characters and hence need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group: replace `\{(\d+)\}` with `$\1$`.